# QT How to do PNG 32bit to a BMP 32bit?

Tags: qt

I want to create a BMP 32bit file.

But will create a BMP 24bit image.

How to do PNG 32bit to a BMP 32bit?

Here's my code

```
QImage image;
image.load("123.png");

QPixmap preview;
preview = preview.fromImage(image,Qt::DiffuseAlphaDither);
preview.save("123.bmp");
```

Answer (score 1):

Concerning Qt 5 source code in qbmphandler.cpp in `bool qt_write_dib(QDataStream &s, QImage image)` bitmaps with 32 bits are supported but converted into 24 bits first (at least 4th channel is ommited).

See here:

```
if (image.depth() == 8 && image.colorCount() <= 16) {
    bpl_bmp = (((bpl+1)/2+3)/4)*4;
    nbits = 4;
} else if (image.depth() == 32) {
    bpl_bmp = ((image.width()*24+31)/32)*4;
    nbits = 24;
} else {
    bpl_bmp = bpl;
    nbits = image.depth();
}
```

You can take a look at my small bitmap handler class [here](http://www.kalytta.com/bitmap.h). May be this can help out.